# what does the php flag -d mean?

Tags: php

I recently saw this page: [PHP cli command line safe_mode restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740353/php-cli-command-line-safe-mode-restriction/11134191#11134191)

Where it is recommended to use the `-d flag` to override php.ini's safe mode setting like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q -d safe_mode=Off /var/www/vhosts/path-to-your-php-file.php
```

I've been searching the net for cron man, php man, php flags etc and nowhere can I find the -d flag.

What is it?

Comment: Shows up just fine in my man page...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stands for an INI property.

```
-d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
```

For future reference, http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: +1 as its exactly as it shows if you type `man php` in unix, that's what I wanted to answer, but you were faster :)

Comment: lol.. that's one of the bad sides of SO.. maybe people should be forced to leave a comment when giving a down vote, not just suggested.. this is obviously wrong.. 7 votes up and one down..